# How to display a div area when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose i have a div id=x which reside in the middle of the page and i want when that page load content in div x to be shown instead of showing the page from top. Its like appending div id at the end of the url to go for a given div area instead this time no url and i want it when page loads

Thank You.

Comment: ok i will Quamis..will the question be closed if i accept a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add `#x` to the end of your URL:

```
window.location.hash = 'x';
```

You could put this in a script tag at the end of your content, so that the content loads first, then the javascript is executed.

E.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hash test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br/>
        ...
        <br/>
        <div id="x">test!</div>
        <script>
            window.location.hash = 'x';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't think that id="x" would work, you should use a named-anchor <a name="x" />

Comment: It seemed to work when I tested it, which browser are you having trouble with?

Comment: my pleasure, I hope the HTML5 format was alright? (`<!DOCTYPE html>`, `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`, `<script>...</script>`)